# How can I install a Linux distribution to my DVD-RW?

Tags: system-installation, livecd, dvd

I have got a DVD-RW on which I'd like to install some linux distributions, but I've tried a few (Ubuntu 13.10, Crunchbang, ElementaryOS and some others, don't really remember), but they didn't work, which has me worried that it might not be possible.

The problem is that I will be using both my USB ports and my HDD for data, so that is not an option.

I'd just like to know if it was possible to install a distribution to my DVD-RW?

If I need to change some config files in the source and compile it myself (which I think is what I need to do), I can do that myself if you could tell me where to look.

Comment: Why don't you buy just another USB flash drive? How many USB ports do you have?

Comment: 2, of which I use 2

Comment: I don't see the point of this... you can use a USB hub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Ubuntu liveCD with persistant storage.

create a file called `casper-rw`.

```
touch /media/casper-rw
```

Then run the folowing command.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/casper-rw bs=1M count=128
```

You will then be able to boot into the liveCD like normal, but any changes made will be saved in the `casper-rw` file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you couldn't do this. I'd approach in the same manner as doing an installation to a USB thumb drive. Take a look at the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key).

You can also use tools such as [Universal USB Loader - Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [UNetbootin - Linux](http://www.techhive.com/article/249870/create_a_bootable_linux_flash_drive_in_three_easy_steps.html) to install ISO images onto USB thumb drives. You may be able to use these types of tools to do what you want as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a linux distro onto a dvd-rw no problem, if you using windows just download some kind of ISO burner. As for them not working have you checked that your primary boot device is set to  rather than your hard disc in the bios?

Comment: I'm not talking about running a live DVD, I'm talking about the actual install, as in using my DVD-RW as the medium that it's installed on.

Comment: I do apologize i misunderstood your question, then no it is not possible as Dvd re writer drives don't have any storage (other than perhaps a cache area). Use a live CD it's probably the best way alternatively get an E-SATA drive to install linux on

Answer (score 0):

If you are not fixed to a distribution, have a look at the [debian live project](http://live.debian.net/). It is a set of scripts which installs a debian (other distributions are possible too) in a chroot environment.

The system will be compressed to a squashfs or similar filesystem and you get an .iso for your DVD after running some scripts.

This DVD will look and feel like a local installation with your personal settings and boot like from hdd.